# jquery active menu lost after clicking on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a simple menu and I'm trying to remove/add an `active` class to the clicked menu item.

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.navbar-nav li').click(function(){
    $('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work/">work</a></li>
    <li><a href="/methods/">methods</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/team/">team</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The issue I'm having is this works but since going to a new page `refreshes` the site once I'm in the new page the active class always goes back to the initial active class in my HTML. I feel like I've done this a number of times and never had this issue. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Are your menu items `active` by default? Isn't it odd?

Comment: @iloo even if I take it out it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you actually need the selector in the event handler? I notice the disparity between $(this) and $('ul.navbar-nav li') , but aren't they the same object? Scratch that, I think the this would refer the the window in that case actually

Comment: @iloo I may not be understanding your comment. But when a user first access the site there needs to be an active menu thats the main reason why I had added it in the first place. Its not necessary and yes not the best idea but not the reason for the code not to work

Comment: Both the page and the javascript is reloaded when you navigate to a different page - so the class you add won't be there on the destination page. If you're using a backend language or a front-end framework then you'd ordinarily set active state using the router logic. If there's no backend involved and you have several static pages then @Xuryon's solution is likely best. Setting the active state using javascript when `ready` is possible, but OTT if you already have static templates that can be unique.

Answer (score 1):

As you redirecting new page on each link click, so dynamically added `active` class is removed on page load. You can do it like following.

Remove the `active` class from `home` menu and add specific href to this like below.

```
<li class="active"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li > a').each(function () {            
        if (window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: None of your li's should have an active class and then add the active class on page load.

/menu.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="work"><a href="/work/">work</a></li>
    <li class="methods"><a href="/methods/">methods</a></li>
    <li class="blog"><a href="/blog/">blog</a></li>
    <li class="team"><a href="/team/">team</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="/contact/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

js could be something like this

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
$('li.' + page).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I'm using the same menu across all pages just including it in

Comment: Then you can't use the click event to change the active link, you'd need to determine which page you are on and then add the active class to the li on window load (or document ready)

Answer (score 0):

There is more than just one file in your project, right?

I would copy the whole `ul` navbar and paste it into every single page. All you have to do after that, is to put the active class on the respective `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things

```
$(function()
 {
   $('ul.navbar-nav li').click(function(event)
   {
    $('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Prevent default would avoid anchor tag tag default action to reload the page. So this should work.

Or if you do not need to go to another page then you can use div instead anchor tag.You can simulate anchor tag behaviour using :hover css selector.

```
div:hover
{
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-style:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="liHome"><a href="/">home</a></li>
    <li id="liWork"><a href="/work/">work</a></li>
    <li id="liMethods"><a href="/methods/">methods</a></li>
    <li id="liBlog"><a href="/blog/">blog</a></li>
    <li id="liTeam"><a href="/team/">team</a></li>
    <li id="liContact"><a href="/contact/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The event handler:

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li').click(function(){
    window.sessionStorage.activeMenuItem = this.id;
});
```

When the page has loaded:

```
if (window.sessionStorage.activeMenuItem) {
    $("#"+sessionStorage.activeMenuItem).addClass('active');
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage:

> A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores.

One problem with this solution is that you cannot open links in a new window, since:

> Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Answer (score 0):

**You're likely in one of three scenarios:**

**A**) You have a collection of static HTML pages with unique content.

**B**) You're using a server-side language and doing some basic `includes`

**C**) You're using a framework with routing logic.

---

**A** If you have two pages both containing the menu code, then it's as simple as moving the default active class.

```
<!-- Home -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work/">work</a></li>
    …
</ul>

<!-- Work -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/work/">work</a></li>
    …
</ul>
```

---

**B** Assuming you're using PHP then something like the following is an easy way to pass this info around:

```
// menu.php
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li <?php if($page = 'home'){ echo 'class="active"' } ?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    …
</ul>

// home.php
<?php
  $page = 'home';
  include(menu.php);
  …
```

---

**C** This will largely depend on the framework you're using, but most will have template helpers that can access the current route, something like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li <% is_route('home') class="active" %>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

---

But adding classes after DOM load with javascript or using session or cookie states is likely over the top.